# Workflow Errors Caused By Absence of Workflow Manager

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, workflow-manager

We are running SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

After a major power outage, we started seeing errors in one of our 2010 workflows. The workflow sets a people field to the context initiator. When one particular user initiates the workflow, it throws an error and does not run. We confirmed this by choosing this particular user via the people picker when editing the list, we get the below error:

> "User does not exist or is not unique"

We previously had installed the Workflow Manager in order to access 2013 platform workflows. I noticed that this service is now not running. Is it possible the absence of this service is affecting this workflow?

Previous to the power outage all workflows were running with no errors.